# Dreamweaver FTP through Bluecoat ProxySG

Tags: proxy, ftp, connection, dreamweaver

Does anyone know how to configure **Dreamweaver** to connect to a remote site through **Bluecoat ProxySG**?

I can connect to FTP through my proxy with Filezilla just fine, and am currently connecting to my REMOTE site that way. I was just wondering if anyone had had ANY luck attempting to FTP from Dreamweaver through Bluecoat ProxySG?

The connection string I use in Filezilla is as follows;

```
USER %u@%h %s
PASS %p
ACCT %w
**-Key for User String-**
%u = Username
%h = Host
%s = Proxy User
%p = Password
%w = Proxy Password
```

The General Proxy box is left blank, but this works a charm. i am using Windows 7 64-Bit SP1 ;) You would think that Dreamweaver would just use the system proxy and have done with :/

If anyone has had ANY luck doing this, please get in touch, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Dreamweaver doesn't have native proxy support, there are a number of 'proxifying' [applications](http://www.proxifier.com/) that'll let you wrap all connections.

Comment: I've had someone else take a look at the documentation to double-check for me. There may only be one persistent primary connection, which would make my last comment wrong, so I've deleted it.

However, you're talking about 'system proxy settings', which implies you have a lot of stuff going through your proxy anyway! You'd have one connection per web-connected program at a minimum. Is one more a breach of your policies?

Comment: I gave the 'proxifying' app a go, but when it does connect all i get is;

An FTP error occured - cannot make connection to host.

Dreamweaver encountered an internal data error. Please try the operation again.

I know my FTP works, I'm beginning to think it's Dreamweaver that's the problem :/

Comment: The answer is correct, i have other issues at play it would seem ;)